# Upload image from other server without resize?

Tags: images

For image upload in my plugin i am using `media_handle_sideload` function. Is it possible to disable image resizing on this function?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `media_handle_sideload` [in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L259). The function within there that generates the intermediate sizes is [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata).

If you just want to upload the file, you can use the [`wp_handle_sideload`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_sideload) function directly and bypass the meta data and attachment generation.